# What is the meaning of "two-sidedness"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

What is the meaning of "two-sidedness"? I'd like a direct or indirect definition.

Comment: If you could provide a context, you would get a more nuanced response.  Do you have the sentence that it is used in?

Comment: Do you mean 'sides' as in edges of a two-dimensional figure, or as in left vs right 'handedness'?

Comment: @gbutters like "things always have two-sidedness".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Two-sided* as defined in [Random House Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/two-sidedness):

> Having two sides;  bilateral.

This is a more direct, literal definition, where the sense of the word applies to concrete things: two-sided coins and two-sided paper.

> Having two aspects or characters.

This is the more indirect, figurative definition, where the sense of the word applies to characteristics of a person, markets, or problems.  The implication is that those things with two-sidedness have a more complex nature than what is presented on the outside.

Adding '-ness' creates the noun form.

Answer (score 1):

Something that has two sides can be called two-sided.  The English suffix *-ness* is used to turn an adjective (or participle) into a noun that refers to the associated quality.  For instance, *darkness* is the quality which *dark* describes.  Thus, two-sidedness is the quality of having two sides.  Although this is not a common word, it is a reasonable one.  One could say, for instance, that a sheet of paper shows two-sidedness.  (It is more likely that *two-sidedness* would be used in a metaphorical sense rather than a literal sense of that example.)

Answer (score 1):

The only occurrence of *two-sidedness* in the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* is in an academic paper dated 1990: ***[he] erred in his prediction that Britain would be one of the superpowers, but he correctly anticipated the “two-sidedness” of world politics after 1945*** (note the quotation marks, which appear in the original, marking that the author knows the word is not standardly used).

@mgkrebbs gave a good description of using the *-ness* suffix to form nouns. *Two-sided* means having two sides, or two aspects. The first meaning is exemplified in a sentence like:

> The set includes 1 00 two-sided letter tiles, four gray bank tiles, and four letter bags

The second can be seen in:

> For the past five years, Pakistan has pursued a risky, two-sided policy toward Islamic militancy

or

> He clearly enjoys having a two-sided conversation.